# Why is my attempt to display an image over the background causing a white display?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview

I have a background coming from Default-568h@2x.png. I want to display a shrunk PNG over part of the background, but calling:

```
[[CJSHCardView alloc] initWithScale:.1];
```

turns the display white. This does not happen if I comment this line, but in the function call, even if I make it return immediately it turns the display white after half a second:

```
- (id)initWithScale:(float)scale
{
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"note.png"];
    self = [super initWithImage:img];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width * scale, img.size.height * scale);
        UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
        myImage.opaque = NO;
        [self addSubview:myImage];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Moving/copying the return statement to be the first in initWithScale makes no discernible change from how it is with the return statement properly at the end: a brief view of the background, followed by a white screen. note.png is in "Supporting Files".

Do you see any gotchas where I can change things so that a shrunken version of the note (maintaining aspect ratio) displays? The note.jpg image does not have a pixel of white.

Thanks,

--EDIT--

Regarding the first comment:

```
@implementation CJSHCardView : UIImageView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    NSAssert(NO, @"Call initWithHeight instead.");
    return self;
}
```

Does that answer your question?

--SECOND EDIT--

Thank you for your response and your code, Nick. I have slightly altered it to fit ARC and to initially set a fixed-width scale, but I was a little unsure of what method to put it in. I tried the ViewController's viewDidLoad() method, but that resulted in the background being shown without hide or hair of the note. My present viewDidLoad() method reads:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-568h"];
    CGRect containerRect = CGRectZero;
    containerRect.size = [backgroundImage size];
    UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:containerRect];
    float scale=.1;

    UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backgroundImage];
    [containerView addSubview:backgroundView];
    [backgroundView sizeToFit];
    // [backgroundView release];

    UIImage *noteImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"note"];
    CGSize noteSize = [noteImage size];
    UIImageView *noteView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:noteImage];
    [noteView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [noteView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, noteSize.width * scale, noteSize.height * scale)];
    [containerView addSubview:noteView];
    // [noteView release];
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: What kind of class is the parent view here? A UIView? How are you setting the parent's frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclassing `UIImageView` is not necessary. Just create a container `UIView` and add 2 `UIImageView` subviews.

Edit - this should work for your implementation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-568h"];
    CGRect containerRect = CGRectZero;
    containerRect.size = [backgroundImage size];
    UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:containerRect];
    [[self view] addSubview:containerView];

    float scale=.1;

    UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backgroundImage];
    [containerView addSubview:backgroundView];
    [backgroundView sizeToFit];

    UIImage *noteImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"note"];
    CGSize noteSize = [noteImage size];
    UIImageView *noteView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:noteImage];
    [noteView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [noteView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, noteSize.width * scale, noteSize.height * scale)];
    [containerView addSubview:noteView];
}
```

Comment: I edited the question to include my attempt to adapt your code. Could you respond to it? Thanks,

Comment: Thank you. When I run it now, it seems to display either the background image, or the note against the background image, but not both, and in particular not the note sitting on the background image. Advice?

Comment: Some other code which you have not posted is probably causing this. You can post your Xcode project if you've not figured it out yet.

Comment: I let it default to an image I hadn't overwritten. When I overwrote the background image, things seemed to work.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!